Update object on click
I'm trying to add a youtube playlist to my website using a tutorial/code. I'm not sure what to do if the there are more than 50 results. I checked the youtube/google api documentation and got a nextPageToken but I'm not sure what to do with it. How do I add pageToken/nextPageToken/prevPageToken objects (?) to the options variable so that it will update the playlist when I click a button? I want to add pagination to the results without reloading the page.
Here is the code from the tutorial. It works as is but I can't view more than 50 videos (the playlist I'm using has about 120). When I add pageToken: nextPageToken to the options, it says that nextPageToken is not defined. How do I define it and the previousPageToken and use them to update the pageToken object and change the results on the page?
$(document).ready(function () {

    var key = [YOUR API KEY HERE];
    var playlistId = 'PL2fnLUTsNyq7A335zB_RpOzu7hEUcSJbB';
    var URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems';


    var options = {
        part: 'snippet',
        key: key,
        maxResults: 50,
        playlistId: playlistId
    }

    loadVids();

    function loadVids() {
        $.getJSON(URL, options, function (data) {
            var id = data.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
            mainVid(id);
            resultsLoop(data);
        });
    }

    function mainVid(id) {
        $('#video').html(`
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                `);
    }

        
    function resultsLoop(data) {

        $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {

            var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
            var title = item.snippet.title;
            var desc = item.snippet.description.substring(0, 100);
            var vid = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;


            $('main').append(`
                            <article class="item" data-key="${vid}">

                                <img src="${thumb}" alt="" class="thumb">
                                <div class="details">
                                    <h4>${title}</h4>
                                    <p>${desc}</p>
                                </div>

                            </article>
                        `);
        });
    }

        // CLICK EVENT
    $('main').on('click', 'article', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-key');
        mainVid(id);
    });


});


Look at the data.nextPageToken in your resultsLoop() function, to see what the next page number is that you can specify for the pageToken value in the options for your next getJSON() call.
See the documentation for more details:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list

Do I have to manually copy/paste every nextPageToken into the pageToken? If so, what do I do with the prevPageToken? How do I use these values to change the listed videos with html buttons? Also, how do I do another call? Sorry I have 0 experience with javascript. Maybe I'm not asking the right questions..

No, just store it in a variable, then as I said, use the value in that variable the next time you call getJSON().  Sounds like you may want to brush up on some basic JavaScript before you try modifying this code. Just a thought.
